# Launching External Intents Works on Cordova 1.6 but not on 3.0 Android

Tags: java, javascript, android, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

I have been developing a Cordova (Phonegap) App that will be able to launch external activities. When using Cordova 1.6 everything works fine, but when I use cordova 3.0 the plugin will not work and I also do not get any output message on the logcat when testing. Bare in Mind that some class names in cordova-1.6.jar have different names than the cordova-3.0.jar, hence when implementing the code there are some minor changes on the imports and on some methods. Below is my complete code using Cordova version 3.0 :

## StartApp.java (Plugin Java Class)

```
package com.example.test;



import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;



public class StartApp extends CordovaPlugin
{
    /**
     * Executes the request and returns PluginResult.
     *
     * @param action
     *          Action to perform.
     * @param args
     *          Arguments to the action.
     * @param callbackId
     *          JavaScript callback ID.
     * @return A PluginResult object with a status and message.
     */
    public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId)
    {
        try {
            if (action.equals("startApp")) {
                if (args.length() != 1) {
                    return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION);
                }
                String component = args.getString(0);
                startActivity(component);
                return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK);
            }
            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Starts an activity.
     *
     * @param component
     *            Activity ComponentName.
     *            E.g.: com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyActivity
     */
    void startActivity(String component) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
        intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString(component));
        cordova.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

## startapp.js(Javascript that calls Plugin)

```
    var StartApp = function() { };

StartApp.prototype.start = function(params, success, fail) {
    success = success ? success : function() {};
    fail = fail ? fail : function() {};
    var component = params.android;
    return cordova.exec(success, fail, 'StartApp', 'startApp', [component]);
};

window.startapp = new StartApp();
```

## config.xml(Here is where I define the plugin

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.helloCordova" version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets">
    <name>Hello Cordova</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <feature name="App">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
    </feature>

    <feature name="StartApp">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.example.test.StartApp" />
    </feature>
    <access origin="*" />




    <preference name="useBrowserHistory" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />



</widget>
```

## Index.html(Html File where I call the plugin)

```
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>

        <button onclick="launchNow()">Launch</button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="startapp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
    <script>

    function launchNow(){
        window.startapp.start(
        {android: 'com.viessmann.etapp/com.viessmann.etapp.activities.SplashScreenActivity'},
        successCallback, failureCallback
        );
    }

    function successCallback(){return true;}
    function failureCallback(){return true;}

    </script>
</body>
```

More reference for cordova 3.0.0 Plugin implementation can be found at :

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_android_plugin.md.html#Android%20Plugins

## !!CODE USED IN CORDOVA 1.6 WHICH WORKS!!!!

## StartApp.java (Plugin Java Class) Cordova 1.6

```
package com.viessmann.launcher;

import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;
import org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;


/**
 * Launches an external application.
 *
 * @author Dmitry Medvinsky <dmedvinsky@gmail.com>
 * @license MIT/X11
 */
public class StartApp extends Plugin
{
    String TAG = "SUCCESS";
    /**
     * Executes the request and returns PluginResult.
     *
     * @param action
     *          Action to perform.
     * @param args
     *          Arguments to the action.
     * @param callbackId
     *          JavaScript callback ID.
     * @return A PluginResult object with a status and message.
     */
    public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId)
    {
        try {
            if (action.equals("startApp")) {
                if (args.length() != 1) {
                     Log.i(TAG, "CLASS CALLED 1");
                    return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION);
                }
                String component = args.getString(0);
                startActivity(component);
                Log.i(TAG, "CLASS CALLED 2");
                return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK);
            }
            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i(TAG, "CLASS CALLED 3");
            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Starts an activity.
     *
     * @param component
     *            Activity ComponentName.
     *            E.g.: com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyActivity
     */
    void startActivity(String component) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
        intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString(component));
        this.ctx.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

## startapp.js (Javascript that calls Plugin) Cordova 1.6

```
var StartApp = function() { };

StartApp.prototype.start = function(params, success, fail) {
    success = success ? success : function() {};
    fail = fail ? fail : function() {};
    var component = params.android;
    return cordova.exec(success, fail, 'StartApp', 'startApp', [component]);
};

window.startapp = new StartApp();
```

## plugins.xml(Defines Plugin) Cordova 1.6

```
<plugins>
 <plugin name="StartApp" value="com.viessmann.launcher.StartApp"/>
</plugins>
```

## Index.html(Html File where I call the plugin) Cordova 1.6

```
function launchNow(){
            window.startapp.start(
            {android: 'com.viessmann.etapp/com.viessmann.etapp.activities.SplashScreenActivity'},
            successCallback, failureCallback
            );
        }

        function successCallback(){return true;}
        function failureCallback(){return true;}
```

Comment: Is the plugin java code called at all (can you put a log statement in there and see if it is called)?

Comment: Hello Mooreds, I added A lOG statement in the JAVA Plugin class (StartApp.java) but did not get any output in the LogCat. What I am going to do is to post the code for Cordova 1.6 that works like a charm and see the differences!

Comment: Original StartApp author here: sorry, I'm not currently doing any Android development and had recently fresh OS install, so I don't even have simulator installed at the moment. Anyway, by any chance do you happen to see some JavaScript errors in the log? Is the `cordova.exec` even executed at all? Maybe add some JS logging (or even `alert`s) before/after the `cordova.exec`. What's the return value of this call?

Comment: Hello dmedvinsky, I am happy to say that I found the solution, and rewrote the plugin class to fit the Cordova 3.0.0 API.. I will soon post the repo on github for everybody to share! ;)

Comment: Do you have any update? :)

Comment: Yes just use git clone git@bitbucket.org:onedigitalsolutions/viessmann-front-end.git if you need any suppost let me know!